# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> DataService]

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, angular8

I have been following tutorials on setting up a mean stack, yet when running my code on localhost I get a blank screen with the error 'StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DataService -> Http]:'. I've spent two days trying to figure out this bug, and couldn't find anything.

As for details on the tools I'm using, Angular 8.3.17, node v12

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  result:any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getAccounts() {
    return this._http.get("/api/accounts")
      .map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import the Http Module and our Data Service
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Import the DataService
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  // Define a users property to hold our user data
  accounts: Array<any>;

  // Create an instance of the DataService through dependency injection
  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {

    // Access the Data Service's getUsers() method we defined
    this._dataService.getAccounts()
        .subscribe(res => this.accounts = res);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add DataService in providers part of app.module.ts file like this

```
providers: [DataService],
```

Comment: Thank you, I've found this earlier today but appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I had to add dataService to my providers array, and HttpModule to imports.

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```